# Trouble using cuechange event and track metadata (HTML5 video)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I've Googled and search for a few days, but I can only find HTML5 video track examples that talk about subtitles, and the ones I've found aren't really complete. Basically, what I would like to do is the following:

-When I enter a cue, I need to access the data for the cue.

-The text data (at least I think it's the text...) contains a number. That number corresponds to an img id elsewhere in my document. I do something to the image then.

This seems like it should be really simple, but I'm not exactly sure where to start. I'm using Jquery.

Here are some snippets of my code:

In my $(document).ready function, I have the following...

```
var t = $("#track1")[0];
t.addEventListener("cuechange", function () {
    var mycue = this.track.cues[0];
    var imgnum = mycue.text;
    var image = $("img#" + txt);//I'm not worried about this part yet...I never get here
    //perform actions on image...
});
```

My html video tag looks like this:

```
<video id="Video1" controls='controls' width="100%" autoplay>
<source src="videos/video-part1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
<track id="track1" kind="metadata" src="test.vtt" srclang="en-us" />
HTML5 Video is required for this example. </video>
```

And my Webvtt file looks like this (The numbers below the time ranges are the slide numbers I need to use)

```
WEBVTT

Test1
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:23.999
00001

Test2
00:00:24.000 --> 00:01:19.999
00121

Test3
00:01:20.000 --> 00:01:39.999
00793
```

When I debugged my code in Chrome the first few times, there didn't appear to be any cue data associated with the track (I checked the cues elsewhere in the code and they were empty). The cuechange event is also not being hooked.
After a while, Chrome started giving me the error about referencing text tracks across domains. I don't know why it suddenly started doing that.

But anyway, in short...

-I don't know how to bind something to the cuechange event correctly (apparently), or the event where you enter a cue either for that matter.

-I don't know how to access the data I need to use.

Just so you know, I also tried kind="captions" and kind="subtitles". Neither one of those worked for me either.
Some help would be lovely. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in you code:

```
//get the track property of the track
var t = $("#track1").prop("track");

//activate track
$.prop(t, 'mode', 'hidden');

$(t).on("cuechange", function () {
    //this already refers to the track object
    //get all activeCues
    var mycue = $.prop(this, 'activeCues')[0];

    //if we don't find an active cue abort
    if(!mycue){return;}
    var imgnum = mycue.text;
    var image = $("img#" + txt);//I'm not worried about this part yet...I never get here
    //perform actions on image...
});
```

You can also try the followin demo http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/QZJTM/